# Ajax Call, Difference between Java Script Ajax call and JQuery Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any Difference if an ajax call is made through the pure Java script way, The JQuery Way or the JASON way.

I have developed some codes using the Java Script way and was thinking if i should change it to JQuery if there are any additional benefits.

If there is no difference i would rather leave it that way and think about it in my next implementation.

Comment: There can be a difference, or might be none, depending on how exactly your code uses AJAX. Right now your question is way too broad.

Comment: Switch to jQuery because jQuery implementation of ajax is better than you and mine ,And it is vastly tested too. :)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is a JavaScript library - it offers a set of functions as helpers, they can include snippets of common functions but also hacks for different browser qwerks.

There are a few things to take into consideration when making an AJAX call, some of the code has to be different for different browsers. Using jQuery they do this work for you and you can just use one easy to use function instead of writing your own fix and having to all the testing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "jQuery way" vs. "JavaScript" way.  jQuery is JavaScript.  JavaScript is the language, and jQuery is a library of functions written by and used with JavaScript.  I'm not sure what you mean by JASON (I think you mean JSON) way unless you are referring to JSONP.

Ajax calls are typically done with the `XMLHttpRequest` object -- at least now.  IE6 and other older browsers may support ajax through other methods such as ActiveX, and even older browsers may not support it at all.

`$.ajax`, the central jQuery ajax method does a lot of work, and [you can actually see what it is](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js), but you may not understand it.  An important line is:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function() {
    try {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch( e ) {}
};
```

Later on we see `xhr = options.xhr()` and then `xhr.send`.  This is all code you would use to make an ajax request with JavaScript without using jQuery.

`$.ajax` also does a lot of other stuff since it can handle JSONP (which does not use XMLHttpRequest) transparently as well as a ton of other things such as supporting different options, setting headers via different methods, etc.  `$.ajax` or *the jQuery way* is simply a wrapper for what you would think of as *the JavaScript way*.